# How to add a custom log level to logger in ruby?

Tags: ruby, logging

I need to add a custom log level like "verbose" or "traffic" to ruby logger, how to do?

Answer (score 6):

Your own logger just need to overwrite the `Logger#format_severity` method, something like this :

```
class MyLogger < Logger

  SEVS = %w(DEBUG INFO WARN ERROR FATAL VERBOSE TRAFFIC)
  def format_severity(severity)
    SEVS[severity] || 'ANY'
  end

  def verbose(progname = nil, &block)
    add(5, nil, progname, &block)
  end
end
```

Comment: IMO, this is a better answer because it avoids the monkey patching of Ruby core. +

Answer (score 4):

You can simply add to the Logger class:

```
require 'logger'

class Logger
  def self.custom_level(tag)
    SEV_LABEL << tag 
    idx = SEV_LABEL.size - 1 

    define_method(tag.downcase.gsub(/\W+/, '_').to_sym) do |progname, &block|
      add(idx, nil, progname, &block)
    end 
  end 

  # now add levels like this:

  custom_level 'TRAFFIC'
  custom_level 'ANOTHER-TAG'
end


# using it:

log = Logger.new($stdout)
log.traffic('testing')
log.another_tag('another message here.')
```

Comment: results in 
`FrozenError: can't modify frozen Array`

Comment: Add the `unfreeze` method via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633367/how-to-unfreeze-an-object-in-ruby then `Logger::SEV_LABEL.unfreeze`

Answer (score 3):

Log levels are nothing but integer constants defined in `logger.rb`:

```
# Logging severity.
module Severity
  DEBUG = 0
  INFO = 1
  WARN = 2
  ERROR = 3
  FATAL = 4
  UNKNOWN = 5
end
```

You can log messages with any level you like using [`Logger#add`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Logger/add) method:

```
l.add 6, 'asd'
#=> A, [2010-02-17T16:25:47.763708 #14962]   ANY -- : asd
```

Comment: This is not going to work well (unless you want to add a level above fatal) because these numbers matter and are used in a comparison 
`return true if @logdev.nil? or severity < level`

Answer (score 2):

If you start needing a bunch of custom stuff, it may be worth checking out [log4r](http://log4r.rubyforge.org/), which is a flexible logging library that lets you do a bunch of interesting/useful stuff easily.

Answer (score -1):

This is an old question, but since it comes up so high on google, I figured it'd be useful to have to correct answer. You can actually use the `Logging.init` method. Here's how you would add a `trace` log level

```
require 'logging'
Logging.init %w(trace debug info warn error fatal)
Logging.logger.root.level = :trace
Logging.logger.root.add_appenders Logging.appenders.stdout
Logging.logger['hello'].trace 'TEST'
```

This is using the `2.0.0` of the `logging` gem.

Comment: But how to use the built-in logger? is using another dependency necessary?

Answer (score -2):

You can create your own logger by overloading the [Logger class](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Logger.html)

Comment: @turri not that I know of. It looks like the levels are pretty much coded in ( Logger::INFO and so on). Maybe there's another way but I can't think of it right now