# How to unfreeze an object in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, there is [`Object#freeze`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-freeze), which prevents further modifications to the object:

```
class Kingdom
  attr_accessor :weather_conditions
end

arendelle = Kingdom.new
arendelle.frozen? # => false
arendelle.weather_conditions = 'in deep, deep, deep, deep snow'
arendelle.freeze
arendelle.frozen? # => true
arendelle.weather_conditions = 'sun is shining'
  # !> RuntimeError: can't modify frozen Kingdom

script = 'Do you want to build a snowman?'.freeze
script[/snowman/] = 'castle of ice'
  # !> RuntimeError: can't modify frozen String
```

However, there is no `Object#unfreeze`. Is there a way to unfreeze a frozen kingdom?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

No, according to the [documentation for `Object#freeze`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-freeze):

> There is no way to unfreeze a frozen object.

The frozen state is stored within the object. Calling `freeze` sets the frozen state and thereby prevents further modification. This includes modifications to the object's frozen state.

Regarding your example, you could assign a new string instead:

```
script = 'Do you want to build a snowman?'
script.freeze

script = script.dup if script.frozen?
script[/snowman/] = 'castle of ice'
script #=> "Do you want to build a castle of ice?"
```

Ruby 2.3 introduced [`String#+@`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-2B-40), so you can write `+str` instead of `str.dup if str.frozen?`

Comment: I especially like your addition mentioning the String#+@ part, since this is fairly new, it appears to be a good use to have mentioned it. I remember I noticed nobu doing some changes there, via the changelog back then, and I did not know about +str.

Comment: The un-freezability is especially important with `Ractor` in Ruby 3.0.

Answer (score 60):

**Update**: **As of Ruby 2.7 this no longer works!**

---

**Yes and no**. There isn't any direct way using the standard API. However, with some understanding of what `#freeze?` does, you can work around it. Note: everything here is implementation details of MRI's current version and might be subject to change.

---

Objects in CRuby are stored in a struct [`RVALUE`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/21daa56b2aa2d4afc6e61b0e6b0f4dd78df620ca/gc.c#L376).
Conveniently, the very first thing in the struct is `VALUE flags;`.
All `Object#freeze` does is set a flag, called `FL_FREEZE`, which is actually [equal to `RUBY_FL_FREEZE`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/21daa56b2aa2d4afc6e61b0e6b0f4dd78df620ca/include/ruby/ruby.h#L1269). `RUBY_FL_FREEZE` will basically be the [11th bit](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/21daa56b2aa2d4afc6e61b0e6b0f4dd78df620ca/include/ruby/ruby.h#L837) in the flags.
All you have to do to unfreeze the object is unset the 11th bit.

To do that, you could use [`Fiddle`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/fiddle/rdoc/Fiddle.html), which is part of the standard library and lets you tinker with the language on C level:

```
require 'fiddle'

class Object
  def unfreeze
    Fiddle::Pointer.new(object_id * 2)[1] &= ~(1 << 3)
  end
end
```

Non-[immediate value objects in Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-object_id) are stored on *address = their `object_id * 2`*. Note that it's important to make the distinction so you would be aware that this wont let you unfreeze `Fixnum`s for example.

Since we want to change the 11th bit, we have to work with the 3th bit of the second byte. Hence we access the second byte with `[1]`.

`~(1 << 3)` shifts `1` three positions and then inverts the result. This way the only bit which is *zero* in the mask will be the third one and all other will be *ones*.

Finally, we just apply the mask with *bitwise and* (`&=`).

---

```
foo = 'A frozen string'.freeze
foo.frozen? # => true
foo.unfreeze
foo.frozen? # => false
foo[/ (?=frozen)/] = 'n un'
foo # => 'An unfrozen string'
```

Comment: Messing around with Ruby's internals is risky. You should address that in your answer.

Comment: @Stefan, I mentioned it in the opening paragraph. I consider it to be self evident.

Comment: I do not consider it to be "risky" - it works perfectly well so I concur with ndn. He provided a very detailed explanation as well, so no surprise that it got many upvotes.

Comment: @shevy well, it depends. It might be perfectly fine to unfreeze the frozen kingdom from the example. But there are objects that don't like to be unfrozen. For example, `:foo.unfreeze` crashes Ruby with a segmentation fault.

Comment: @Stefan, indeed I stated that it works only for non-immediate value objects.

Comment: @ndn you're right, I've totally overlooked that. But does a symbol have immediate value? Nevertheless, there could be situations where the frozen state of an object is taken for granted and changing it would lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: @Stefan, according to the documentation, immediate values are used for *nil, true, false, Fixnums, Symbols, and some Floats*

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks.

Comment: How would you do this without creating a new method on Object, for one time use-cases?

Comment: @Jonathan I would execute the body of the method for that object. Aka `Fiddle::Pointer.new(stuff_to_unfreeze.object_id * 2)[1] &= ~(1 << 3)`.

Comment: This doesn't work with ruby 2.7.x and produces a segmentation fault. Any alternative?

Comment: In 2.7, `object_id` is no longer related to the address of the object.

Comment: @ehbello: one alternative is to use the accepted answer, "following the rules" of how this is meant to work, and `dup`licating the object to get a version one can modify.  Of course, depending on the type and size of the object, this may be costly or otherwise cause difficulties (the semantics of this are different than unfreezing), however for the typical/casual case, this is probably the correct thing.  For that reason _and_ because this answer self-admits to not working in 2.7+, I'm downvoting this answer. I guess it was "risky" after all!

Comment: Is there any way to unfreeze in Ruby 3.03 as it is not working with the above solution?

Answer (score 5):

```
frozen_object = %w[hello world].freeze
frozen_object.concat(['and universe']) # FrozenError (can't modify frozen Array)
frozen_object.dup.concat(['and universe']) # ['hello', 'world', 'and universe']
```

Comment: This doesn't modify the object, it modifies it's copy.

Comment: Because of you shouldn't "unfreeze" frozen objects in Ruby, it's supposed the purpose of this functionality is basically keep your objects immutable. Even Rubocop, time ago introduced a rule where every single .rb should have "The magic Ruby comment" and constants should always have a frozen state. Ruby 2.6 already comes with this feature by default.

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer.  Duplicate the variable and modify it as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

As noted above copying the variable back into itself also effectively unfreezes the variable.

As noted this can be done using the .dup method:

`var1 = var1.dup`

This can also be achieved using:

`var1 = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(var1))`

I have been using `Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(`  ... `)`

I have not used `.dup` and only learned about it through this post.

I do not know what if any differences there are between `Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(`  ... `)`

If they do the same thing or `.dup` is more powerful, then stylistically I like `.dup` better. `.dup` states what to do -- copy this thing, but it does not say how to do it, whereas `Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(`  ... `)` is not only excessively verbose, but states how to do the duplication -- I am not a fan of specifying the *HOW* part if the *HOW* part is irrelevant to me. I want to duplicate the value of the variable, I do not care how.

Comment: As noted above, this doesn't modify the object, it modifies a copy.