# Freezing string literals in early Ruby versions

Tags: ruby, jruby

This question applies in particular to Ruby 1.9 and 2.1, where String literals can not be frozen automatically. In particular I am refering to [this article](http://flats.github.io/blog/2016/01/03/frozen-strings/), which suggests to freeze strings, so that repeated evaluation of the code does not create a new String object every time, which among other advantages is said to make the program perform better. As a concrete example, this article proposes the expression

```
("%09d".freeze % id).scan(/\d{3}/).join("/".freeze)
```

I want to use this concept in our project, and for testing purpose, I tried the following code:

```
3.times { x="abc".freeze; puts x.object_id }
```

In Ruby 2.3, this prints the same object ID every time. In JRuby 1.7, which corresponds on the language level to Ruby 1.9, it prints three different object IDs, although I have explicitly frozen the string.

Could somebody explain the reason for this, and how to use `freeze` properly in this situation?

Comment: String interning makes strings immutable, but making strings immutable does not guarantee string interning. The `freeze` contract only specifies it will make a string immutable, no more and no less. Whether or not a string is interned is not defined, and each implementation can choose the behaviour for itself.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: How so? At `unfreeze`, you'd just have to copy it somewhere else (so that any references to the "canonical" icicle would remain valid). This changes `object_id`, obviously, but... I think `Hash` already does something similar... `a = "foo"; b = { a => 1 }; a.object_id == b.keys.first.object_id` is false

Comment: Lol, you're right (barring [shenanigans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633367/how-to-unfreeze-an-object-in-ruby)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In particular I am refering to this article, which suggests to freeze strings, so that repeated evaluation of the code does not create a new String object every time

That is not what [`Object#freeze`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-freeze) does. As the name implies, it "freezes" the object, i.e. it disallows any further modification to the object's internal state. There is nothing in the documentation that even remotely suggests that `Object#freeze` performs some sort of de-duplication or interning.

You *may* be thinking of `String#-@`, but this does not exist in Ruby 2.1. It was only added in Ruby 2.3, and actually had different semantics then:

- Ruby 2.3–2.4: returns `self` if `self` is already frozen, otherwise returns `self.dup.freeze`, i.e. [a frozen *duplicate* of the string](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.7/String.html#method-i-2D-40):

  > ## `-str` → `str` (frozen)
  >
  > If the string is frozen, then return the string itself.
  >   If the string is not frozen, then duplicate the string freeze it and return it.
- Ruby 2.5+: returns `self` if `self` is already frozen, otherwise returns a frozen version of the string [that is de-duplicated](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-2D-40) (i.e. it may be looked up in a cache of existing frozen strings and the existing version returned):

  > ## `-str` → `str` (frozen)
  >
  > Returns a frozen, possibly pre-existing copy of the string.
  >   The string will be deduplicated as long as it is not tainted, or has any instance variables set on it.

So, the article you linked to is wrong on three counts:

1. De-duplication is only performed for strings, not arbitrary objects.
2. De-duplication is not performed by `freeze`.
3. De-duplication is only performed by `String#-@` starting in Ruby 2.5.

There is also a fourth claim that is wrong in that article, although we can't really blame the author for that since the article is from 2016 and the decision was only changed in 2019: [Ruby 3.0 will *not* have immutable string literals by default](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11473#note-53).

The one thing that *is* correct in that article is that the `# frozen_string_literal: true` pragma (or the corresponding command line option `--enable-frozen-string-literal`) will not only freeze all static string literals, it will also de-duplicate them.