# What are the ways to override a frozen variable in ruby?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

This is a selenium-webdriver **commands.rb** file where I want to edit the **upload_file** key of **COMMANDS** variable from **[:post, 'session/:session_id/se/file']** to **[:post, 'session/:session_id/file']**. I want to extend this class to one of mine's and make this change permanent so that even if i **bundle install** it, this change shouldn't be gone.

```
module Selenium
  module WebDriver
    module Remote
      module W3C
        class Bridge
          COMMANDS = {
            upload_file: [:post, 'session/:session_id/se/file']
          }.freeze

        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question, please? It is very unclear to me. a) You cannot freeze variables, only objects. b) You cannot override variables, only methods. So, what does it mean to "override a frozen variable" if you can't override variables and there is no such thing as a frozen variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get around the issue of unfreezing by just assigning the constant to a new value:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::W3C::Bridge.const_set(:COMMANDS, {
 upload_file: [:post, 'session/:session_id/file']
}.freeze)
```

You will get a warning, but it will work.

If you really want to unfreeze, I have to point you to another question on the topic: [How to unfreeze an object in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633367/how-to-unfreeze-an-object-in-ruby)

---

*in response to comment*

The easiest way is to use ActiveSupport [Hash#deep_dup](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/deep_dup) from ActiveSupport. If this is a non-rails project, you can add the `activesupport` gem and `require 'active_support/all'`:

```
my_commands = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::W3C::Bridge::COMMANDS.deep_dup

# Here we can change one key only, or do any other manipulation:
my_commands[:upload_file] = [:post, 'session/:session_id/file']
Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::W3C::Bridge.const_set(:COMMANDS, my_commands)
```

You can also do it without ActiveSupport, but you will need to be a little more careful about how you clone the object because `deep_dup` is not available, something like this would work instead:

```
my_commands = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::W3C::Bridge::COMMANDS.clone.transform_values(&:clone)
```

And then run the same stuff as in the previous example.

To understand this, read up on the difference between a "shallow" vs "deep" copy of an Object in Ruby, or the difference between "clone" and "deep_dup". Also see [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) which I used in that snippet, if you're not familiar with it.

Comment: You can also use [`remove_const`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Module.html#method-i-remove_const) first to clear it out and avoid the warning.

Comment: Is there a way to edit only one of the symbol and not as a whole? Like, if COMMANDS hash has more than one key-value pairs and I need to edit only one of it and the other one shouldn't be disturbed. Any help on this?

Comment: Edited answer @SanjeevKumar